# np.arrayの累乗でRuntime warningが発生する

Tags: python, numpy

numpyの2次元配列の累乗(要素ごとの累乗)が正常にできず困っていましたので教えてください。

環境：
Python: 3.7.5
Numpy: 1.17.4

float32型・2次元のnp.array（正または負の実数値を格納、一部NaNを含む）を1.514乗しようとすると、``**`でも`np.power()` でも以下のエラーが発生して全てNaNになるか、その要素を1.514乗した値ではない値が格納されたnp.arrayが返されます。

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```

fooはfloat32型で，気象データの配信サーバーからNetCDF形式で取得してきたものです。

NaNが入っているからか？と思い、要素を一つとりだして1.514乗した場合、以下の記述でもRuntime warningになります。

```
foo[0][0] ** 1.514
(foo：2次元のnp.array)
```

ところが、以下の方法でループで要素を一つずつ抜き出して再格納した配列varをつくり、`var ** 1.514` をすると正常な値が戻ってきます。

```
var = np.zeros((len(lat), len(lon))
for i in range(len(lat)):
    for j in range(len(lon)):
        var[i][j] = foo[i][j]
(fooがオリジナルのnp.array)
```

この方法を使えばとりあえず問題は解消できますが、気味が悪いので原因を教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ここでいう累乗とは、行列の積を繰り返すという意味での行列累乗ですか？　それとも、行列の要素ごとの累乗（element-wise な累乗）ですか？　また、累乗をする直前の `foo.dtype` の正確な値を教えてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
Element-wiseという意味という意味です。たとえば，
a = ([2,3,4],[5,6,7])という行列があったとして
aの各要素のn乗 ([2^n, 3^n, 4^n],[5^n,6^n,7^n])を求めようとしています。

foo.dtypeはfloat32です。

Comment: numpy の場合、実際には libc の power function を呼び出しています。[Ubuntu Manpage: pow, powf, powl - power functions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man3/pow.3.html) には、"**x is negative**, and **y is a finite noninteger**, errno is set to EDOM. An invalid floating-point exception (FE_INVALID) is raised." と記載されています。例えば `np.array(-1.0) ** 1.514` などとすると同じワーニングメッセージが表示されます。これを回避するには、`np.power(abs(array), 1.514) * np.sign(array)` などとします。

Comment: metropolis様：貴重な情報ありがとうございます。負値が入っているとまずいのですね。教えていただいた方法を試してみます。

中身をうつしただけの```var```にも負値が入っているのですが，```var**1.514```はエラーにならないのがますます謎です。

Answer (score 2):

どうも numPyの `power()` 関数は、負や複素数の累乗には対応していないようです。
私も同じことでひっかかってしまい、この質問に達しましたが、いろいろとぐぐっているうちに、英語のページに同様の質問があり、同様の推察がなされていました。

2乗などの時は、おそらくこの問題は発生しないのですが、1.7乗などとすると、対象がマイナスでなくてもエラーになるようです。

私の対策としては、`abs()` で絶対値をとってしまうことで、多少効率は悪くなりますが対応できました。

```
z = np.power(abs(x), y)
z = abs(x)**y
```

という感じです。